# Add new column for edit/delete when data is loaded in dataTables library

Tags: javascript, datatables, server-side

I have a *dataTables* table which its data is loaded by ajax call. Each row has 5 columns. The configuration is as follow:

```
<table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width: 100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PersonnelId)</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NationalId)</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Companies)</th>
      <th>Operations</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

for initialization i use:

```
var table = $('.table').DataTable({
    "proccessing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        url: "server_api.php",
        type: 'POST'
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "FirstName" },
        { "data": "LastName" },
        { "data": "PersonnelId" },
        { "data": "NationalId" },
        { "data": "Companies" }
    ]
});
```

Considering each row has an **Id**, how can i add [Delete](http://#) / [Edit](http://#) for each row in the **operations** column?

Comment: First, you need to create a php function which connects to databese and deletes the item. Then you need to create a new table column for the delete item. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764230/reloading-a-datatable-without-refreshing-with-ajax) is a SO post for a starter.

Comment: Server side is created, my problem is to create additional column

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. To add data to an additional column you need to

1. add a column when initializing and
2. fill the column cell in the **rowCallback** function.

The code is:

```
var table = $('.table')
                .DataTable({
                    "proccessing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "ajax": {
                        url: "server_api.php",
                        type: 'POST'
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        { "data": "FirstName" },
                        { "data": "LastName" },
                        { "data": "PersonnelId" },
                        { "data": "NationalId" },
                        { "data": "Companies" },
                        { "render" : function() {return ""; }
                    ],
                    "rowCallback": function (row, data) {
                        var additionalColIdx = 5; // Index of new column
                        $(`td:eq({additionalColIdx})`, row).html("<a href=\"edit.php/" + data.Id "\">Edit</a>" + " / " +
                                "<a href=\"delete.php/" + data.Id + "/" + "\">Delete</a>");
                    }
                });
```